# Bash script read a string with whitespace

Tags: bash, git, whitespace

I am trying to write a quick bash script to automatically git push to multiple branches at once. My issue is, when I enter my commit message as a read variable, bash and git freak out at the use of whitespace.

Here is my current script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
echo "Pushing To all branches"
echo "What is your Commit Message?"
read message

git add *
git commit -m \"$message\"
git push origin
.... (push to other branches) ...

echo "Done!"
echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
```

And this works perfectly if my commit message is only one word. However, this is often not the case. For example, if I enter:

```
Testing test case
```

as my commit message, I would get the following errors:

```
error: pathspec 'test"' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'case"' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this so that my bash script can handle whitespace?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You are escaping the quotes around `$message` causing it to perform word splitting.

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is calling `git commit -m` with literal double quotes as part of the message.

The command line given to `git` will be, if `$message` is the string `some message here`,

```
git commit -m '"some' 'message' 'here"'
```

This is due to quoting the double quotes.

Instead, this would work:

```
git commit -m "$message"
```

---

Use a commit message template instead.

Assuming that the template is in the file `template.txt` like so:

```
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Pushing To all branches
# What is your Commit Message?
```

... then this would be inserted in the top of the commit message in an editor when you do

```
git commit -t template.txt
```

Providing an editor to edit the commit message in would make it much easier for the user to properly format a correct commit message.

You may also set the `commit.template` in the repository's `.git/config` file to the pathname of a template file to use (`-t` is not needed then).

Any line starting with `#` in the template will not be committed.

See also:

- http://codeinthehole.com/tips/a-useful-template-for-commit-messages/
- https://robots.thoughtbot.com/better-commit-messages-with-a-gitmessage-template